# PostgreSQL How to know this server is PG Pro or not?

Tags: database, postgresql

Do you know how to know by sql query that postgresql version is PostgreSQL PRO or not?

Comment: Postgresql pro seems to be a Russian thing,  I's reccomend against suing it outside of Russia, Iran, and North Korea.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution: use following query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings where name = 'pgpro_version'
```

Check empty result or not.

Comment: There is no such thing as PGPro. Postgres is fully open source and does not have community vs. pro versions. Perhaps you are thinking of *EDB EnterpriseDB (Advanced Server or Extened Server)* both paid services, based upon PostgreSQL. BTW there is no `pg_settings` with value 'pgpro_version'. To get the version in Postgres run `select version()`.

Comment: @Belayer, is  your database Postgresql Pro or not? In my non-pro version  the parameter pgpro_version is absent, but in pro version - it exists.